# How to send data in 'GET' request of XMLHttpRequest in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, xmlhttprequest

and thanks for investing your time in this post.

I want to send a data in GET request in XMLHttpRequest.

```
function useAjax(url,data){
        const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onload = function(e) {
            const resData = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText) ;
            setResponseData(true,resData)
        }
        xhttp.open("GET", url, false);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.send(data);
   }
```

I tried to make change on open function params like xhttp.open("GET", url, [false,data]);

but still getting no result

Comment: Just like you'd do it for any GET request, add the data into URL as a queryString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

["Get" request has no body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET), to send some data use "POST"

[If the request method is GET or HEAD, the body parameter is ignored and the request body is set to null](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

Answer (score 0):

For a C# based API, you can specify [FromHeader] in your method signature and then send the object in the header using `XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader`...

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'http://your-host/route/endpoint');
...
xhr.setRequestHeader('MyFilter', {"item":"value", "item":"value" })
xhr.send();
```

then in your controller (C#):

```
[HttpGet("route/endpoint")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetListOfMyObject([FromHeader] MyFilter filter)
{
    var result = QueryForDataUsingObject(filter);
    ...
}
```

Object will be automatically deserialised into the required type.

Comment: This is about sending a GET request, rather than defining GET endpoints.